# JS switch what form returns to a b64 string

Tags: javascript, forms, html-input

I want to save an image in b64 format in my database. For reasons I want to deal with the logic on the frontend side of things. My backend sends a form and already encapsulates the filefield input with a `onChange` function that converts img -> b64:

```
<form>
    <input id="file-select" name="pic" class="form-control" type="file" onchange="getImage()">
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

where `getImage()` looks like this:

```
function getImage() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var f = document.getElementById("file-select").files;
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        console.log(reader.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(f[0]);
}
```

How can I replace what the input field submits on button press with the value of `reader.readAsDataURL(f[0])`?

Comment: A base64 image is 1/4 larger than the original image. It's never wise to store images as base64 strings. Specially not into a database table. Save it as is, as binary file to a server folder as `IMAGEHASH.EXT`. Inside the database store the image name, the extension, the hash and the user ID.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I use it for icon storage (filesize < 4kb).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem: *"How can I replace what the input field submits on button press with the value of"*

Comment: I want that the b64 string is sent to the backend, not the img field. The `onchange` function  creates this `DataURL` object, how can I send this to my backend?

Answer (score 2):

- Use the input `value` property
- Don't use inline `on*` JS handlers (same as hopefully you don't use inline `style` attributes). Use `addEventListener()` instead
- Add a missing Form's `action` attribute for the URL you're sobmitting to
- Add a `required` attribute to your Input Element

```js
const EL = (sel, el) => (el || document).querySelector(sel);

const EL_file = EL("#file-select");

const readFile = () => {
  if (!EL_file.files) return;
  const FR = new FileReader();
  FR.addEventListener("load", (evt) => EL_file.value = evt.target.result);
  FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
};

EL_file.addEventListener("change", readFile);
```

```html
<form id="file-form" action="save_base64.php">
  <input id="file-select" name="pic" class="form-control" type="file" required>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```